# how to make user choose from one value in a list

Tags: python

In line 5, how do I make it in such a way, that if preference == one of the fruits and not all? Also, the input returns a string right? How can I make the user choose a value from the variable? I'm quite new so forgive me if i'm making dumb mistakes, thanks!

```
fruits = ['banana', 'pineapple', 'strawberry', 'mango']
preference = input('What fruit would you like?')
if preference == 'nothing':
    print('Sorry to hear that, goodbye!')
elif preference == fruits:
    print('That\'s great! I\'ll be back in a moment with your order.')
    if preference == preference[0]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference[0])} dollars')
    elif preference == preference[1]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference[1])} dollars')
    elif preference == preference[2]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference[2])} dollars')
    elif preference == preference[3]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference[3])} dollars')
    print('Thank you for your purchase! Goodbye!')
else:
    print(f'Here\'s our menu! We have {fruits[1:3]} and {fruits[-1]} here.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the keyword `in`:

```py
elif preference in fruits:
```

And you should also check each preference to each value in fruits. Not to itself. Same thing applies to printing the length of your preference. You indexed your preference which means if your preference was "banana" it would take the 0th index or "b". Which will always have a value of 1. Corrected code:

```py
fruits = ['banana', 'pineapple', 'strawberry', 'mango']
preference = input('What fruit would you like?')
if preference == 'nothing':
    print('Sorry to hear that, goodbye!')
elif preference in fruits:
    print('That\'s great! I\'ll be back in a moment with your order.')
    if preference == fruits[0]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference)} dollars')
    elif preference == fruits[1]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference)} dollars')
    elif preference == fruits[2]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference)} dollars')
    elif preference == fruits[3]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference)} dollars')
    print('Thank you for your purchase! Goodbye!')
else:
    print(f'Here\'s our menu! We have {fruits[1:3]} and {fruits[-1]} here.')
```

That means your don't need to check which fruit it was at all! That will make it simpler for you. Like this:

```py
fruits = ['banana', 'pineapple', 'strawberry', 'mango']
preference = input('What fruit would you like?')
if preference == 'nothing':
    print('Sorry to hear that, goodbye!')
elif preference in fruits:
    print('That\'s great! I\'ll be back in a moment with your order.')
    print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(preference)} dollars')
    print('Thank you for your purchase! Goodbye!')
else:
    print(f'Here\'s our menu! We have {fruits[1:3]} and {fruits[-1]} here.')
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work still? It doesn't display the price

Comment: I have updated my answer for another bug.

Comment: oh my god! Thank you so much! That is so much more shorter and simpler, thanks!!<3

Comment: Oops, I almost forgot, 1 last question if you don't mind. The last line returns 
Here's our menu! We have ['pineapple', 'strawberry'] and mango here.
Why? And how do I make it not display the brackets?

Comment: To join the list with a separator, let's say ", ", we need to do this: ```", ".join(list)```. This will return 'pineapple, strawberry'.

Comment: So for your code, ```", ".join(fruits[1:3])``` instead of ```fruits[1:3]```

Comment: Ah I see! Thank youu! 
print(f"Here\'s our menu! We have {', '.join(fruits[1:3])} and {''.join(fruits[-1])} here.")

Comment: Yes, but not completely. You don't need to join ```fruits[-1]```, because that is referring to a single item in the list, which would print out normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
# your code goes here

fruits = ['banana', 'pineapple', 'strawberry', 'mango']
preference = input('What fruit would you like?')
if preference == 'nothing':
    print('Sorry to hear that, goodbye!')
elif preference in fruits:
    print('That\'s great! I\'ll be back in a moment with your order.')
    if preference == fruits[0]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(fruits[0])} dollars')
    elif preference == fruits[1]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(fruits[1])} dollars')
    elif preference == fruits[2]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(fruits[2])} dollars')
    elif preference == fruits[3]:
        print(f'Here you go! That would be {len(fruits[3])} dollars')
    print('Thank you for your purchase! Goodbye!')
else:
    print(f'Here\'s our menu! We have {fruits[1:3]} and {fruits[-1]} here.')
```

you need to use `in` to check if `value` is inside a `list` or not.

also, `fruits` is a list where you are checking the `preference`, so use `fruits` instead of `preference`

Comment: So I change the 5th line to 'fruits in preference' ? I did this but it said 'Expected type 'str', got 'list[str]' instead'.
Also why isn't the price displayed?

Comment: you are checking if the input preference is inside a fruits list or not.  so use `if preference in fruits` not `fruits in preference`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much!